# Python pygame function not defined

Tags: python, pygame

I've been asked to find a problem with my cousin's Pygame code. I'm not big on Python, using other languages more and I haven't been able to find the issue by googling or debugging. Basically he's getting a *"`playGame` is not defined"* error, `playGame` being a function. Other questions about this are usually because:

1. The function is called before it is declared
2. The function is declared inside a different scope from which it is called

Neither of these seems to be the issue so I'm hoping someone more versed in Python can spot it. I've copied his code below with a lot of what (I hope) is irrelevant to the question removed to simplify.

The function `playGame` is not working and is called by a button click under
`def button(msg, x, y, action = None):`
. Interestingly the exit function is working fine which is called and declared exactly the same as `playGame` as far as I can tell.

```
# --------------- SETUP ---------------
# Importing necessary modules
import pygame
import math
import random
# --------------- DISPLAY ---------------
# Setting up the display
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption(title)
# --------------- GLOBALS ---------------
#removed globals from stackoverflow version


# --------------- FUNCTIONS ---------------


# Blitting the text
def blitText(angle, power):
    #code


# Drawing the tank model
def drawTank():
    #code


# Creating the buttons
def button(msg, x, y, action = None):
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()                                                                           # Gets the mouse position
    mouseClick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    (buttonWidth, buttonHeight) = (175, 45)                                                                     # Sets the button width and height
    if x + (buttonWidth / 2) > mousePos[0] > x - (buttonWidth / 2) and y + buttonHeight > mousePos[1] > y:      # Checks if the mouse is over the button
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, darkGrey, [x - (buttonWidth / 2), y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight])                   # Draws a dark grey button
        if mouseClick[0] == 1 and action != None:                                                                   # Checks if the button is clicked
            if action == "play":
                playGame()
            elif action == "exit":
                exit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, grey, [x - (buttonWidth / 2), y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight])                       # Draws a light grey button if not

    screen.blit(msg, [x - (buttonWidth / 2), y])                                                                # Writes the text over the button


# Defining the shell
class shell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):              # Creates the shell() class
    def __init__(self):                             # Defines an initiation fuction for this class
        super().__init__()                              # Call the parent class constructor
        self.image = pygame.Surface([2, 2])             # Defines the bullet as a 2x4 surface
        self.image.fill(black)                          # Paints the bullet black
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()               # Gets the area size of the bullet

    def update(self):                                                                                                                               # Defines a function as update for this class
        (bulletChangeX, bulletChangeY) = (((maxAngle - angle) / maxAngle) * (bulletSpeed * power), (angle / maxAngle) * (bulletSpeed * power))          # Ccalculates the changes in x and y
        bulletChangeY -= vert                                                                                                                           # Changes the trajectory of the bullet
        self.rect.y -= bulletChangeY                                                                                                                    # Moves the bullet in the y axis
        self.rect.x += bulletChangeX                                                                                                                    # Moves the bullet in the x axis


# --------------- TITLE SCREEN ---------------
# Creating the main menu
menu = True
while menu:                                                     # Starts the loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:                                   # Checks if pygame has been closed
            exit()                                                          # Exits python
    screen.fill(white)                                              # Fills the screen white
    screen.blit(titleText, [0, 0])                                  # Writes the title text

    button(startButton, width / 2, (height / 3) * 2, "play")      # Calls the button function for the start button
    button(exitButton, width / 2, ((height / 3) * 2) + 70, "exit")    # Calls the button function for the exit button

    # Updating the display
    pygame.display.update()                                         # Updates the display
    clock.tick(fps)
# --------------- MAIN LOOP ---------------


# Running the program
def playGame():
    #code. This function has no return value.


# --------------- EXIT ---------------


# Exits PyGame and Python
def exit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Hopefully the mistake is obvious here to someone and I haven't removed any key code that is causing the problems (I removed start variable declarations and the contents of function code) I can provide the full code if people need it.

Comment: It is called when a button is clicked:
    def button(msg, x, y, action = None):
Defining the game above everything else is something I have already tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, just found it. So, where is `button` used? It seems like it should be used as a callback, but maybe you are calling it instead, e.g. you have `command=button()` instead of `command=button` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Note that `exit()` is a builtin function in Python, so the fact that `exit` is found is not telling anything; it is probably just using the builtin.

Comment: I see. It's being called with parameters. I've updated the question to include the call code which is under the `---TITLE SCREEN---` heading of the code.

Comment: Yup, there it is: Instead of creating a button (what I'd assume you were trying to do) you immediately check whether the mouse was clicked in some region and then call the function, which is not yet defined. Unfortunately, I can not tell you how to properly define a button with a callback function, but now someone else should be able to help you.

Comment: you have to put `def playGame()` before `while menu` because `while menu` is executed before `def playGame()` so `playGame` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks tobias! Just knowing where the problem lies is good for me - I don't want to write his code for him, just help him since he's been stuck on this for over a week! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, themistake is obvious - as you put it:

The cod e is trying to call the function before it is defined - 
the `while menu` code which draws the menu screen and draws the button is placed before the `playGame` function - which name is undeclared at that point.

While Python does run code on the module top-level, the best pratice is to leave only some constant and variable declarations on the toplevel, and putting code like the block `while menu: ...` inside a function. (Which may be called `main` - but there is no top language requirement on its name)

Then, at the very bottom of the file, make a call to that function, with a call placed - this time correctly, at the module body -

So - something along:

```
def main():
    # Creating the main menu
    menu = True
    while menu:                                                     # Starts the loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:                                   # Checks if pygame has been closed
                exit()                                                          # Exits python
        screen.fill(white)                                              # Fills the screen white
        screen.blit(titleText, [0, 0])                                  # Writes the title text

        button(startButton, width / 2, (height / 3) * 2, "play")      # Calls the button function for the start button
        button(exitButton, width / 2, ((height / 3) * 2) + 70, "exit")    # Calls the button function for the exit button

        # Updating the display
        pygame.display.update()                                         # Updates the display
        clock.tick(fps)
```

And at the very bottom, place a single `main()` call would make that particular error go away.